# what can be the problem behind if my android phone charges just 2-3% in 1 hour?

Tags: charging

This happens with me so many times. I want my answer please tell me. IOt will be a great help for me. I believe in stack exchange !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buy an Ampere-meter for USB-port like this

[LED USB Voltage & Current Detector Power Supply Amp Tester for Mobile Power ETDS](http://www.ebay.de/itm/like/400874390840?ul_noapp=true&chn=ps&lpid=106)

Then try different charger/cable combinations until you find one that works for you.

Keep in mind that the ampere-meter may influence charging behaviour.

Comment: Thnx !!! I have tried another charger and it worked. The problem was with the charger.

Answer (score 1):

Might be your charger, in conjunction with whatever is going on with your phone while it is charging.

Check the fine-print on your charger for the output current value (measured in amperes "A" or milliamps "mA"). My Samsung charger which came with my S5 charges my phone in little over an hour. The charger supplies 2A (amperes) of current. Another charger I have supplies 800mA of current (less than half what my Samsung charger provides) and takes a few hours to charge.

Sometimes, if I am streaming a movie or playing games while charging, the charge takes even longer, since the amount of current needed to run those actions is almost as much as what the charger can provide.

This is an over-simplistic explanation, but I think it may help.